# Is it possible to tell if a function is recursive?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, reflection

Is there any way short of reading and parsing a file to see whether a function uses a for loop vs. recursion to get its answer?  Assume it can be only one or the other, that the function doesn't raise, and that the function is guaranteed to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "basic" conditions, you can at least tell if a function will call itself directly:

```
def test(x):
    return test(x)

test.__code__.co_name in test.__code__.co_names  # true and co_name can't be changed
test.__name__ in test.__code__.co_names  # true but name can be changed
```

This checks if the name of the function is in the global names referenced by the function.

I say "basic" because there are a bunch of ways someone can probably get around this.  Lambdas don't have a name, so they won't match the global name they were bound to.  A function could be renamed.  The inner code could reference a different name for the function.  The function could call a second function, which is the real recursive function.  And on and on...

Basically, there is no way to know for sure that a function is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

There is not general method to prove that a computer program finishes (it is proven that there are programs for which you cannot tell). Fortunately, in practise there are static analysis tools, that can do this for most of small programs.

Also, for most of Python functions it is either obvious what complexity they have (for an educated programmer) or it is mentioned in documentation what algorithm is used.

If you are interested in details, you should read a good book or two about algorithms. You can also take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ , which is a site better suited for general discussion about computational complexity of different algorithms.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but this wasn't the question - I stated that I wanted to use the assumption that the program finishes and that it isn't an incorrect function. Not to prove that. What I want to determine programmatically is whether a function uses recursion or a loop. I realize this may not be possible, but this was the actual question. I am aware that you cannot programmatically determine whether a function ends, but I figured this might be a different question (perhaps by looking at the stack or something).